# Replace AEAddressDesc in apple event

Tags: macos-carbon, appleevents

I have an apple event, and I need to resend this event to the other process. Can anyone tell me how?

```
static void GetEvent(AppleEvent *event)
{
    RgnHandle       cursorRgn = NULL;
    Boolean         gotEvent;

    gotEvent = WaitNextEvent(everyEvent, event, 32767L, cursorRgn);

    if (gotEvent)
       // AEProcessAppleEvent(event);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ProcessSerialNumber psn;
    AppleEvent event;

    GetEvent(&event);
    GetProcessForPID([childProcess processIdentifier], &psn);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`AEAddressDesc` is a type, so your question as stated doesn't make sense.

What you're really asking to do is set the address of an event. That's an attribute; namely, [the `keyAddressAttr` attribute](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Apple_Event_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/keyAddressAttr). Set it as you would any other attribute of an Apple Event descriptor.

Comment: I write code:

`ProcessSerialNumber psn;
DescType retType;
Size actualSize;
AEAddressDesc target;
GetProcessForPID([childProcess processIdentifier], &psn);
err = AEGetAttributeDesc(&event, keyAddressAttr, typeSInt32, &target);
err = AEReplaceDescData(keyAddressAttr, &psn, sizeof(psn), &target);
AESendMessage(&event, NULL, kAENoReply | kAENeverInteract, kAEDefaultTimeout);`

But into `AEGetAttributeDesc` get an error `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`. What I doing wrong? Please, explain me how to works with this 'descriptors', 'attributes' and 'parameters'. I can't understand that from documentation.
Thanks.

Comment: I tried it's early: 
`err = AEGetAttributeDesc(&event, typeProcessSerialNumber, retType, &tmpDesc);
AEReplaceDescData(typeProcessSerialNumber, &psn, sizeof(psn), &tmpDesc);`

Comment: @Lexandr: I don't know why you're calling `AEGetAttributeDesc` or `AEReplaceDescData`, and you're not setting the target of the event. Descriptors contain attributes and parameters, which are generally key-value pairs (like in a dictionary). Just about everything in the Apple Event Manager, including Apple Events themselves, is a descriptor.

Comment: Please, can you tell me how to set target of the event? Little sample code. In 'AppleEvents.pdf', which from apple developer site, describes: create event, get data (by param, by attribute), set data (AEReplaceDescData) and create event.

Thanks.

Comment: @Lexandr: There are a couple of functions, but for your purpose, you'll want [the `AEPutAttributePtr` function](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Apple_Event_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AEPutAttributePtr).

Comment: I got an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` during `AEPutAttributePtr(&event, keyAddressAttr, typeProcessSerialNumber, (void*)&psn, sizeof(psn));`. 
'event' - is an event, where I did changes. 'keyAddressAttr' - is a key for attribute into event, which I want to replace/place. 'typeProcessSerialNumber' - is type of data, which I put to a attribute data. 'psn' - pointer to data to put (ProcessSerialNumber).
Tell me please, what I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: @Lexandr: Please edit your question to include the code from the declarations of `event` and `psn` to that line.

Comment: `ProcessSerialNumber psn; AppleEvent event; ... GetEvent(&event); GetProcessForPID([childProcess processIdentifier], &psn); AEPutAttributePtr(&event, keyProcessSerialNumber, typeProcessSerialNumber, (void*)&psn, sizeof(psn));`
I trying also `AEPutAttributePtr(&event,keyProcessSerialNumber,typeProcessSerialNumber,(void*)&psn,sizeof(psn));`, but again got exception.

Comment: @Lexandr: Please edit your question to also include the code that creates the Apple Event. (Don't post it in a comment; as you can see, it gets all mashed up into one line.)

Comment: @Lexandr: `WaitNextEvent` returns an `EventRecord`, not an `AppleEvent`. That's because it's part of the Event Manager (for handling user-input events), not the Apple Event Manager (for sending and receiving inter-application messages called Apple Events). You should ask a separate question about what you're trying to do there.

Comment: But in developer documentation said, that EventRecord and AppleEvent can be used interchangeable.

Thank you.

Comment: @Lexandr: Where did you see that?

Comment: Citation: "An Apple Event Manager function that operates on one of these data structures can also operate on any type that inherits from it.", "Similarly, you can pass Apple events and Apple event records, as well as descriptor lists and descriptors, to any Apple Event Manager function..." (Apple Events Programming Guide (Legacy))

Comment: @Lexandr: “Apple event record” is defined here: http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/building_aes_aepg/building_aes_aepg.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001449-CH203-BEJJGABC It is unrelated to the `EventRecord` type used by the Event Manager. The type of an Apple Event record is `AERecord`.